# Running into problems with omniauth with multiple providers. Should I use an omniauth.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I want to implement omniauth-instagram and omniauth-facebook into my Rails project and keep running into problems and also keep getting confused by all the resources that are out there.

I want to focus on this resource:
[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

The resource above mentions:
`Remember that config.omniauth adds omniauth provider middleware to your application. This means you should not add this provider middleware again in config/initializers/omniauth.rb as they'll clash with each other and result in always-failing authentication.`

I want to clarify what this means in relation to the **config/initializers/omniauth.rb** mentioned in other documentation.

**My actual question:**
Should I have an **omniauth.rb** file or does the **devise.rb** configuration (as posted below) work in place of it?

**devise.rb**

```
  require "omniauth-instagram"
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if Rails.env.development? 
  config.omniauth :instagram, 'client_id', 'secret_key'
```

Any points in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Question was already answered by kengo: No, you don't need `omniauth.rb` if you are configuring omniauth with `devise.rb`. Also, you don't need the following line: `require omniauth-instagram` since Bundler already requires the gem for you (that's why you add gems to the Gemfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use devise+omniauth to enable users to login through facebook. The setup is in config/initializers/devise.rb. I don't have omniauth.rb.

devise.rb looks like this.(only omniauth part)

```
 Devise.setup do |config|

   # ==> OmniAuth
   # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
   # up on your models and hooks.
   # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user,public_repo'

   config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'

 end
```

Also, your devise.rb is too short. You can generate devise.rb template and using this command.

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @kengo!  And yes... my devise.rb file is actually a lot longer but didn't want to include it in my entire question.